# I use Visual Studio 2010. I want to change the cursor position when a button is clicked. how do i do it?

Tags: c#

I tried the `Cursor.Position`, but it isn't working. I want it to point to a textbox. What should I do? Should I create a cursor object or something like that?

Comment: Why do you want to change the cursor position? a more standardized way to inform the user that they need to type something is to Focus() the textbox.

Comment: web ? windows forms ?

Comment: Please provide more information. What language? WPF? WinForms? MVC? Etc?

Comment: As the OP has mentioned Cursor.Position, this appears as though it will be a Windows Forms application. It does not seem that this property exists in WPF or ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouse_event to set the cursor, its a win32 function so you need to pinvoke
Be sure to set the absolute flag

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event

Answer (score 0):

```
PointConverter pc = new PointConverter();

Point pt = new Point();

pt = (Point)pc.ConvertFromString("0, 100"); //X,Y value

Cursor.Position = pt;
```

Try this solution.
Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/f7eeb890-a87d-4dbb-9ea8-a77ded3ee363/changing-the-mousecursor-position

Comment: Why using `PointConverter`? `pt = new Point(0, 100);` does the same.

Comment: Different solution, same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was written as a Windows Forms application.

Put this in your button event handler. This will move the cursor to the exact center of the textbox (textbox1):

```
Point p = new Point(textBox1.Location.X + textBox1.Width / 2, textBox1.Location.Y + textBox1.Height / 2);
Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(p);
```